# A calculator's modulo and percentage labels

Tags: buttons, mobile-application

I'm designing a UI for my calculator.

I've got a modulo function and a percentage of function.
I started with a "%" button for the modulo, but now I need something different that clearly says "This will calculate the percentage". What should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use the modulo function's abbreviated name

The [abbreviation for modulo is mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

The abbreviation **Mod** will fit on a calculator button, as illustrated on the right version:

[image]

This particular illustration is from a Windows Phone 7 calculator design, and the image itself came from this [blog post about Modernist ("flat") user-interface design](http://fivesketches.com/modernist-design-beyond-flat-and-simple/). In the image the "Rotate left" and "Rotate right" labels refer to something described in the blog post.

#### Then, use % for percentage

I just looked at your question again (did you rewrite it?), and noticed I didn't answer your question. But by implication, once you use **Mod** for modulo, then the **%** label is available for percentage. You can see this in the illustration, above.

Comment: interesting how different calculators use different sets of programmer, math and language symbols ( `x` `*`, `/` `div-symbol`). what does it say about the designer and user targeting? :)